# Form submit status flag in Angular 2

Tags: angular, form-submit, angular-ng-if

I want to display a form submission flag that will eventually become an animation to the users whilst they wait for their results.

I am working with the following function:

```
  onSubmit(): void {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.applicationForm));
    this.formState = 'submitted';


    this.submitService.submitApplicationForm(this.applicationForm)
      .then(
      success => this.handleSubmissionResponse(success),
      failure => this.handleSubmissionResponse(failure)
      );
  }
```

In my form component class I have:

```
export class SendAnswers implements OnInit {

submitStatus = "We are getting your results..."
status = "submitting"
```

Then a basic function to change the above label

```
  submitState(newStatus){
    this.submitStatus = newStatus;
    this.status = (this.status === 'submitting' ? 'We are getting your results...': 'Your results are below');
  }
```

The Status flag:

```
  <div *ngIf="this.formState === 'submitted'">
      <h3>{{submitStatus}}</h3>
  </div>
```

How do I call `submitState` after my `ngIf` statement if you can no longer have `ng-init` in angular 2?

Comment: use submitState method inside on submit before making a service call, then  change the status use same method inside success after you get results. Show some other useful message by using error handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how do i call submitState when my app first loads my component?

If that's the case, then that's the purpose of the ngOnInit life cycle method on components. This method is automatically called by Angular on initialising a component.

So you can add your initial submitState call in that ngOnInit method.

btw, since your component implements the OnInit interface, then that ngOnInit method should already exist on your component.

**Edit**

So assuming you have your onSubmit and submitState as two methods on your component, you can adjust your onSubmit to something like:

onSubmit(): void {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.applicationForm));
    // this.formState = 'submitted';  <--- why is this here???

```
this.submitState('submitting');

this.submitService.submitApplicationForm(this.applicationForm)
  .then(
  success => {
    this.submitState('submitted');
    this.handleSubmissionResponse(success);
  },
  failure => this.handleSubmissionResponse(failure)
  );
```

}

```
submitState(newStatus){
    this.submitStatus = newStatus;
    this.status = (this.status === 'submitting' ? 'We are getting your results...': 'Your results are below');
```

}

Comment: Good point on OnInit But where do I call SubmitState do that it adds the newStatus to <h3> depending on the FormState? At the moment, nothing triggers the method.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question then. You call submitState when it makes sense to do so. If you want to call it when the component first loads, then that's the purpose of the ngOnInit. If you want to call it when you trigger your submit and then again after the submit finishes, then call it in you onSubmit method at the start to kick off the submitting and then in your handleSubmissionResponse method when you want to 'end' the submitting status.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am trying to understand "How to call the "submitState" method from "onSubmit()", do I need an event emitter somewhere?  makes sense?

Comment: If I try to call it from the onSubmit method I get: `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'String' has no compatible call signatures.`

Comment: i updated the answer with a code example.  that error that you're getting suggests that you're trying to treat a String variable as a function